# How to save dict of DataFrames by copy?

Tags: python, pandas, copy, deep-copy

I have DataFrame with positionsSnapshots. One row is some position at some timestamp. I want to collect info about all positions at each timestamp and create dict with keys - timestamp of latest change in position and value - DataFrame with unique positions ID.

My version return all DataFrames equals.

```
df_positions_snapshots.sort_values('timestamp', inplace=True, ascending=False)
df_positions_snapshots.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
latest_state = df_positions_snapshots.drop_duplicates('POS_id')
df_positions_snapshots_last = df_positions_snapshots.drop(index=latest_state.index)

next_state = latest_state.copy()
states[next_state['timestamp'].max()] = next_state.copy()
ind_copy = df_positions_snapshots_last.index
states = {}

for ind in ind_copy:
    row = df_positions_snapshots_last.loc[ind, :].copy()
    if row['POS_id'] in next_state['POS_id']:
        next_state.replace(to_replace=next_state[next_state['POS_id'] == row['POS_id']], value=row, inplace=True)
    else:
        next_state.append(row)
    states[row['timestamp']] = next_state.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need the DataFrame to be saved as a dictionary? Would another method of serializing work (i.e CSV, Pickle, etc.)?

There is the [pandas method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) `pd.to_dict` that I would suggest you use. If this is not what you are looking for, could you give more detail or provide a dummy input and output dataset?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2],
               'col2': [0.5, 0.75]},
              index=['row1', 'row2'])
df.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'col1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 2}, 'col2': {'row1': 0.5, 'row2': 0.75}}
```

Comment: It's one of there method, but later I will need these DataFrames, so I can use to_dict and later DataFrame from_dict. But it looks like not nessary operations.

Comment: I need dict with type of values is DataFrame. I don't need transform DataFrame in dict.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem what you are trying to express. use

`import copy`
`copy.deepcopy`

This will allocate the unique DF elements that you are expecting, wont return the duplicates

Comment: Pandas copy is also deep by default. Is there some difference?

Comment: @Дмитрий yes you are right !! it does the copy(defult=True).  then m answer wont help you here honestly speakig.